# remove duplicates based on one field in a numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

How do I remove duplicates when a numpy array field has duplicates.

for example, i have an array like this:

```
vals = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[1,5,6],[1,8,7],[0,4,5],[2,2,1],[0,0,0],[5,4,3]])

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 5, 6],
       [1, 8, 7],
       [0, 4, 5],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [5, 4, 3]])
```

i need to remove the duplicates for field `[0]`, so that i got the results like:

```
([1,2,3],
[0, 4, 5],
[2, 2, 1],
[0, 0, 0],
[5, 4, 3]])
```

Comment: Does this have to be done as an array operation or would you accept it being performed using lists.  The latter is much easier to implement and for small arrays the performance difference will be negligible.

Comment: Should the row `[0, 0, 0]` be removed too?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

```
In [11]: vals
Out[11]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 5, 6],
       [1, 8, 7],
       [0, 4, 5],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [5, 4, 3]])

In [12]: unique_keys, indices = np.unique(vals[:,0], return_index=True)

In [13]: vals[indices]
Out[13]: 
array([[0, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [5, 4, 3]])
```

To maintain the original order:

```
In [17]: vals[np.sort(indices)]
Out[17]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [0, 4, 5],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [5, 4, 3]])
```

Comment: if there are two column have duplicates. how should the code be changed then? such as based on the first column and second column, if first column and second column both duplicates, then remove one duplicates

Comment: i actually just tried it on my numpy array. It gave me error saying too much indices for an array. My array have like a million records

Comment: Re: *two columns...*  Please edit the question to include all the relevant details.  Re: *error*... Edit the question to include a simple example that demonstrates the error.  Include a copy of the complete traceback (i.e. the full error message) in the question.